# Device Tree for DSA with KSZ9897

Tags: ethernet, i2c, kernel, modules

I have a custom board with a [KSZ9897](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ9897S-Data-Sheet-DS00002394C.pdf) switch chip and a LAN7801 upstream. The KSZ9897 is connected to the Compute Module via i2c, and I can see it at `0x5f` using `i2cdetect`.  Everything appears to be working correctly from a hardware perspective, but I can not seem to [get the linux driver](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/1c64f4bc22811d2d371b271daa3fb27895a8abdd/drivers/net/dsa/microchip/ksz9477.c) to work.

I have compiled and installed a custom kernel version with `CONFIG_NET_DSA_MICROCHIP_KSZ9477=m` and `CONFIG_NET_DSA_MICROCHIP_KSZ9477_I2C=m`, which is successfully producing the modules I'd expect. I can load them with `modprobe` with no errors.

What I cannot get my head around, is how the dt config is applied [as shown in the documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/1c64f4bc22811d2d371b271daa3fb27895a8abdd/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/net/dsa/ksz.txt). I've attempted adding the bits I need as options in `/etc/modules` and also manually when loading the driver.  Nothing presents errors, but nothing seems to work either.

I think this is more of a question about modules and the device tree than the hardware itself, any guidance would be much appreciated.